# How to extract years from a string that contains a date range [Typescript/Angular]

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm a beginner in Typescript. I have a date range which I'm receiving as a string.

```
var range="7-01-2018 VS 5-01-2019";
```

It is hard coded right now just to explain you. But it will be in this string form only later also. I've to extract 2018 and store it in some variable, say `startYear` and also I've to extract 2019 and store it in `endYear` variable. So that later I can compare them and apply validations.

I tried using:

1. **substring(start,end)**

My code worked but the problem is that the string will change its length when a double digit date is selected. For eg:

1. `7-01-2018 VS 25-01-2019` or
2. `17-01-2018 VS 5-01-2019` or
3. `27-01-2018 VS 25-01-2019`

In these cases `start` and `end` will have different meanings. What should I do now. Please help me.

My method is:

```
myValidator() {

  range="7-01-2018 VS 5-01-2019";

  startYear=range.substring(5,8);

  endYear=range.substring(18,21);

  if(endYear<startYear) {
    console.log("Invalid range");
  }
}
```

Now I'm planning to use `split()`. And split the string into different parts and then write some logic with that. But the problem with split is that there's a `VS` in between. However for `separator` parameter i can give `-` symbol. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: use `split` to seperate your string into 2 parts(split by `VS` if confirmed). then parse the date(`split` by `-` is ok in this case).

Comment: That 's a good one. Ok. I'll implement this and come back to you if required. :-)

Comment: if your program have a lot of date manipulation, I suggest you to use moment.js (https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @CHANist. I'm sorry. I'm not allowed to use anything outside the organisation. Otherwise I would've used primeng diirectly. I've to create from the scratch.

Comment: @Narro. Output: `[Array(5) [ "1", "01", "2019 VS 3", "01", "2019" ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are right split will be  good

```
myValidator() {

      range="7-01-2018 VS 5-01-2019";

      startYear=parseInt(range.split("VS")[0].split("-")[2])

      endYear=parseInt(range.split("VS")[1].split("-")[2])

      if(endYear<startYear) {
        console.log("Invalid range");
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is `x` here. You mean `range`? Right ?

Comment: was consoling your input ,so typed that :)

Answer (score 2):

- Using `String.prototype.match`

```
const range = '7-01-2018 VS 25-01-2019'


const [...range.matchAll(/\d{0,2}-\d{0,2}-(\d{0,4})/g)].map((date)=> date[1])
```

Comment: This question is about extracting only the year and not the whole date. Good use of regex though

Comment: I just realised your regex is incorrect it should be `\d{0,2}-\d{0,2}-(\d{0,4})`. However since you're only extracting the year it would still work in this case

Answer (score 2):

All in one line

```js
const [,startYear,endYear]=range.match(/.*-(\d{4}) VS .*-(\d{4})$/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `split`, `Date` and `reduce`:

```js
console.log("7-01-2018 VS 25-01-2019: ", checkRange("7-01-2018 VS 25-01-2019"));
console.log("7-01-2019 VS 25-01-2018: ", checkRange("7-01-2019 VS 25-01-2018"));

function checkRange(inputRange) {
  const range = inputRange.split(" VS ");
  const getYear = dateStr => 
    new Date(dateStr.split("-").reverse().join("-")).getFullYear();
  const years = range.reduce( (acc, val) => [...acc, getYear(val)], []);
  return years[0] < years[1];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, edited for array of integers as Output

```
myValidator() {
  range = "7-01-2018 VS 5-01-2019";
  regEx = /\d{4}/g;
  return (range.match(regEx).map(x => parseInt(x,10));
}
Output :
[ 2018, 2019 ]
```

Comment: Sir I want them to be an integer. As I mentioned in the question also. I've to compare them later. Like, which one is greater and how much. Some arithmetic is also involved.

Comment: It should work now and the output would be array of integers. If you are not following arrow function, you can convert that into a regular one.